# Rails : API - Devise : current_user return nil even if signed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, devise

I am developing a Rails API and using Devise for authentication.
I am testing the sign in and out via curl command.

The problem is current_user always returns nil in other controllers even if I am signed in (by using the curl command).

Curl commands:

```
Sign in :        
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions -d "{\"user\":{\"email\":\"user1@example.com\",\"password\":\"secret123\"}}"
```

Sign out :
    curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X DELETE http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions/\?auth_token\=JRYodzXgrLsk157ioYHf

Comment: Please post the cURL command(s) you're using.

Comment: Sign in :
    curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions -d "{\"user\":{\"email\":\"user1@example.com\",\"password\":\"secret123\"}}" `

Sign out :
    curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X DELETE http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions/\?auth_token\=JRYodzXgrLsk157ioYHf

Comment: The only way Rails knows you're "signed in" is if your request includes the cookies the server sent you when you signed in. You need to tell cURL to record those cookies and send them with subsequent requests. See the `--cookie-jar` option in `man curl`.

Comment: @Jordan It did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your approach is not correct. Devise's `current_user` method depends on a cookie that is saved on the browser to indicate if a user is signed in or not.

I suggest you use another approach, say by generating a token for each user and sending it along with each request. You can make an authentication endpoint that takes a user email and password, and generates a token specific for this user if the credentials are valid. Then in all requests that require user login, you should send this token along with any other parameters.

For a simple implementation of this, you can check [#352 Securing an API - Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api) (a bit old but still valid).

Or for a more secure solution, you can check out [Doorkeeper gem](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper).